# How to get previous task's actual owner in JBPM?

Tags: jbpm

Is there a way in JBPM to get who has completed the previous task?

Example:

Task A  ->  Task B

In Task B, I want to have a variable to be displayed actualOwner of task A

Answer (score 1):

Get taskService object in OnEntry script of TaskA like as:

```
kcontext.getKieRuntime().getEnvironment().get("RuntimeManager").getRuntimeEngine(ProcessInstanceIdContext.getContext(processInstanceId)).getTaskService()
```

Once TaskService object is available use "getTaskById(long taskID)" to get the task details. Or easy way is saving the 'ActorId' field of a task in a process variable and later pass it to the next human task.

Answer (score 0):

In task A, you can create an output Varible "actor", that will get the injected value of user that has owned the task, with {#user}